# Conditional Inner Join Statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables in SQL Server. Their are no PK / FK in the tables so I have to join on a few conditions.

What I want to have happen is if I am unable to match on my first criteria I then want to join on different criteria. I was thinking there could be way to do this using a case statement... If it matches on my first condition then all is good, if it does not match on the first condition then try to join on a different condition.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.DOS = CAST(SUBSTRING(Table2.SurgeryDate, 6, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Table2.SurgeryDate, 9, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Table2.SurgeryDate, 1, 4) AS DATE)
         AND Table1.DateOfBirth = CAST(SUBSTRING(Table2.BirthDate, 6, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Table2.BirthDate, 9, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Table2.BirthDate, 1, 4) AS DATE)
         AND Table1.Gender = CASE WHEN Table2.gender = 'Male' THEN 'M' 
                                  WHEN Table2.gender = 'Female' THEN 'F' 
                                  ELSE 'U'  
                             END
         AND LTRIM(RTRIM(Table1.HspId)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(Table2.HspId))
---If those people who do not match on the above criteria then I would want to match them on their last name.
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You have several major challenges going on here. The first is that it seems like you are storing strings and/or ints as dates instead of using the proper datatype. Using LTRIM(RTRIM( on an ID column is also a big red flag. But the biggest and most obvious issue is right here. "Their are no PK / FK's in the tables". Of course we really can't help you here because we have no idea what your table structures are like. Maybe starting here would be a good idea. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: To answer the question posed, look at OR. Meaning you want to join on a = b OR c = d.

Comment: @SeanLange  Thanks for the feedback - Yes agree that store data type correctly would be great.  Our development team that manages our DB does seem to care much about properly storing data. The data sets that I want to join are coming from different companies so their wouldnt really be any primary or foreign keys.

Comment: Since the data is coming from different companies, wouldn't it make more sense to have an ETL process that massages their data to be more like what you expect so your joins are consistent?

Answer (score 3):

Sample data will be needed to give a specific answer, but here are a couple general approaches:

You can use `OR` while ruling out the previous condition:

```
SELECT cols
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
               OR (t1.col1 <> t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2)
```

Note you have to rule out the previous condition to create the join predicate hierarchy and avoid duplicates.

Another way is to use repeated `LEFT JOIN`s for each condition and add `NULL` handling:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.col1, t3.col1)
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t3 ON t1.col2 = t3.col2
WHERE COALESCE(t2.col1, t3.col1) IS NOT NULL
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first non `NULL` value.  The `LEFT JOIN`s will return `NULL` if the join does not find a match row.  Thus, the select `COALESCE()` is handling 'displaying' the correct column based on the join hierarchy order. The where `COALESCE()` is filtering out the rows where none of joins are successful (recreating the `INNER JOIN` you have in your current query)

The second approach, while ugly, can perform better because `OR` queries have trouble optimizing properly.

Comment: Aaron, I know this is an old post but you really helped me out with your answer above.